# How does blade handle script calls?

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables, laravel-blade

Hi once again everyone.

I'm having a problem with script calls. I'm using blade in laravel.

Everything is working the right way except the scripts calling, which support search and order functions.

Here is my hierarchy and respective relevant code:

**main.blade.php**

```
...

    <div class="page-container">

      @include('layouts.sidebar')

      <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->

      <div class="page-content-wrapper">

        <div class="page-content">

         @yield('body')

       </div>

     </div>

   </div>

 . . .

        <script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/global/scripts/datatable.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/pages/scripts/table-datatables-managed.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

      </body>

      </html>
```

**permissions.blade.php**

```
@extends('mainPage.main')

@section('body')

. . .

@yield('userListBody')

. . .
```

**userList.blade.php**

```
@extends('administration.permissions')

@section('userListBody')

. . .
```

And this produces the following
[image: User List View]

while when I use the following structure for a different view:

**main.blade.php**

**listagem.blade.php**

```
@extends('administration.permissions')

@section('userListBody')

. . .
```

[image: File List View]

as you can see it doesn't apply pagination, search or order function even though it's loaded.

[image: Script Load]

The script that is handling this is called here

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/pages/scripts/table-datatables-managed.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've been trying to get this to work but unsuccessfully. What am I missing?

Also if I move the script call to the **userList** it doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance and if anything else needed ask so I can provide the necessary information.

Edit 1: After finishing some other stuff I was doin in this project decided to get back at this...

I think it may be important to add this information
**script.js**

```
var TableDatatablesManaged = function() {
    var e = function() {
            var e = $("#sample_1");
            e.dataTable({ . . . });
```

And I've tried to remove the script call from the **main.blade.php** and add to end of **listagem.blade.php** and **permissions.blade.php** and it doesn't work on both views.

I have this same line in both views

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover order-column" id="sample_1">
```

I've also made another function with another name and tried to call it on **listagem.blade.php** changing the id but without success again.

Comment: hi, sorry, i can't see your images as the url is blocked by my network's proxy (cant be unblock lol), are there errors in the browser's console?

Comment: None of them? Anyway I can share the images with you?

No, the script is called, it appears in green, but for some reason it doesn't provide all the options when I list the files. The options appear when I I list the users...that's why I can't quite understand what is happening

Comment: image.prntscr.com works for me :)

Comment: You should be able to see everything ok now! If you need anything else or want me to test some stuff out feel free to ask.
Btw as you probably already noticed I'm still kinda new to all this (web development) so it might be just another silly mistake

thanks for your time!!

Comment: Can you eliminate your JS as the cause here?