# Laravel Controller $request not receiving AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm having a problem understanding what I'm doing wrong.

My **route.php**

```
Route::get('/changeUserPermissions', 'UserController@getchangeUserPermissionsView');
Route::post('/changeUserPermissions', 'UserController@changeUserPermissions')->name('postPermissions');
Route::get('/changeUserData', 'UserController@changeUserData');
```

And both my **Controllers.php**

```
public function getchangeUserPermissionsView(Request $request)
{        dd($request->ajax()); //returns false
// or dd($request->all()); -> returns []
}

public function changeUserData(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $usernames = Input::get('usernameSend');

        if(isset($usernames)){
            $user = User::Where('username', '=', $usernames)->first();
            return redirect()->to('/settings'); 
        }else{
            Log::warning("Username não existe na base de dados.");
        }
    }
}

public function changeUserPermissions(Request $request) //Route::post
{
    return view('notUsedAtm');
}
```

and my **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){

        if((this.id).indexOf("dados") != -1){

            var content = this.id.replace("dados_", "");

            $.get('changeUserData', {usernameSend:content, '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),}, function(data){

                window.location.replace('settings');

            }).fail(function(err, status) {

                alert("There was an error. Try again please!");

            });


        }else if((this.id).indexOf("permissoes") != -1){

            var content = this.id.replace("permissoes_", "");

            $.get('changeUserPermissions', {usernameSend:content, '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),}, function(data){    

                window.location.replace('changeUserPermissions');    

            }).fail(function(err, status) {

                alert("There was an error. Try again please!");    
            });   
        }   
    });    
});
```

My view calls are exactly the same except for the id name. By this I mean that my buttons are all equaly declared with their id being different from each other.

Now changeUserData works and the same with changeUserState (which is called in my jQuery script). Both receive the request and get it as AJAX, but changeUserPermission doesn't.

As posted in the code commented, if I dd the request and ask if it's an AJAX request it returns false if I do request->all() it just returns an empty array.

Any ideia what it might be? Been searching for a while now and couldn't find anything.

Edit: Took out some code in order to make it shorter and more readable.

Edit 2: Everything works fine route-wise. For instance the **$.get('changeUserPermissions'...)** is calling the right route, everything I do on the route works just fine. The only problem is it doesn't recognize the ajax request. Also **dd($request->isMethod('get'))** returns true.

Here is a print of **dd($request)**. If you need something expanded say so and I'll post.

[image]

Comment: do you get redirected after sending the `changeUserPermisions` ajax request? or you are alerted that there was an error?

Comment: If I leave as it is the page is reloaded and appears a blank page with fail (because of the die and dump on the controller). If I return a view on the controller I get redirected to the view with all the parameters I've set...the only problem is it doesn't recognize the ajax request and I need to get some data from the request....i'm unable to user Inpute::get() for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing the flow of your code when sending AJAX `get` request to `/changeUserPermissions`

Step 1:

`get` request sent to `/changeUserPermissions`

This is the Route for that:

```
Route::get('/changeUserPermissions', 'UserController@getchangeUserPermissionsView');
```

Step 2:

This function gets fired.

```
public function getchangeUserPermissionsView(Request $request)
{        dd($request->ajax()); //returns false
// or dd($request->all()); -> returns []
}
```

Note: this will still be a successful AJAX response, so, moving on...

Step 3:

Since the AJAX request is successful, the following code will run:

```
window.location.replace('changeUserPermissions');
```

**WHICH** performs a `get` request to `/changeUserPermissions` thus firing again the function in **STEP 2**, but now, without any data included.

That's what I see that is happening in your code.

I think what you're seeing as empty/false is the **latest** `get` request for `/changeUserPermissions` which happened in **STEP 3** (which is why `$request->ajax()` is returning `false`)

**Additional:**

You can see the actual `dd($request->ajax())` of **STEP 2** in your browser's dev tools, since it is an AJAX request, you can see it in *Network* tab, just find the request, it will probably be named `/changeUserPermissions`

Comment: This is what I get from firefox tool: 
https://image.prntscr.com/image/K-nFjKjcQWyNeOPg4SEY6A.png

But then how can I send the data? I need to do something like this (with the respective validations, but that isn't the important here:
**$username = Input::get('usernameSend');
return view('administration.permissoes', compact('username''));**

Comment: can you right click the request and open it in a new tab? or you did it already? also, note that you are using AJAX request, returning a view won't reload the page.

Comment: Did that already. The return is too long to post here as text.

But I understand what you said and in fact I'm doing 2 get requests but in the second i'm going to the pretended view.

Now what I want to know is how can I return a view in the first AJAX request? The one i'm sending the data? Should I set a **onclick** event on the button to redirect? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: if you return a view, you'll receive the contents of the view. That's different from redirecting. Try returning the view from the ajax request and **PREVIEW** the response, you'll see a webpage. I think one thing you can do is not to make it an AJAX request. What's the sense of doing ajax request when you want to redirect immediately in the end?

Comment: I was using AJAX so I could send data from the view to the controller. I have a table with data from several users. When I click a button I want it to go to another page and send the username with it. But I don't want to send the username through the link as many suggest in several questions.

Comment: why not. you can do `{username}/changeUserPermissions`, that's easier, and don't need AJAX. just make sure you have enough authorization and authentication to make the feature secured. that is just username, that's ok, you can see in stackoverflow when you visit anybody's profile, it uses the user id.

Comment: Oh ok! Thought it wasn't secure
One last thing, since it's related to the same project, do you have any insights on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252968/how-does-blade-handle-script-calls?

Thanks for your help and guidance on AJAX requests. I finally understand what is going on, on my requests and how they work.

Comment: You're welcome. Ill try to comment on that later. As my trip home is the worst xD goodluck on what you're doing! :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the URLs in your `$.get` are correct?

Should they be `/changeUserData` and `/changeUserPermissions`? (note the leading `/`).

Also, should `changeUserPermissions` be a `POST` since that's how it's defined in your routes?

Lastly, you sending a `BODY` via `GET` will not give you the results you expect.

Based on the info you've provided, this should work:

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/changeUserPermissions', 'UserController@getchangeUserPermissionsView');
Route::post('/changeUserPermissions', 'UserController@changeUserPermissions')->name('postPermissions');
Route::post('/changeUserData', 'UserController@changeUserData'); // This should be `POST`, `PUT`, or `PATCH`
```

**jQuery**

```
$.post('/changeUserData', { usernameSend: content, '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content') })
 .done(function (data) {
    ...
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    ...
})

$.post('/changeUserPermissions', { usernameSend: content, '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content') })
 .done(function (data) {
    ...
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    ...
})
```

See [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more info and ways to post data via jQuery. If you want to use `put` or `patch`, I believe you'll need [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Edited the main topic with aditional information.
The way it is it works. If I use .get('/changeUserPermissions') jQuery sends an alert saying something was wrong.
I need a **get** and a **post** method for **changeUserPermissions** because in this jQuery script I just return a view, but I need to get some data related to the user. After that I need to return data from the database (on another script), that's why I need the post route. I just posted both because it could be some kind of conflict.
And changeUserData is a get since it only returns a view, no?